# Set element to unclickable and then to clickable

Tags: jquery

I want to have a div element set to not be clickable and then set it to clickable after another element is clicked.

So, when .case is clicked:

```
$('.case').click(function() {  
$('#patient').addClass('active').on('click');
});
```

But how do I set #patient to unclickable in the first instance when I have further down:

```
$('#patient').click(function() { 
alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: What does "clickable" mean? Do you mean having a click event? Do you mean having `cursor: pointer`?

Comment: to accept a click event..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
$('#patient').on('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        // do whatever when it's active.
    }
    return false;
});
```

If you just want it to not accept, you can add this to your css ([pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)):

```css
#patient { pointer-events: none; }
#patient.active { pointer-events: auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see how this could work, but I was wondering if there was a way to set an element to not accpt click events...   I'll give your solution a try out in the meantime.

Comment: Added css that will stop click event from being triggered in most browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Four days on SO and already 581 points...!  Well you have more now, many thanks for your help!

Comment: To be fair, I've been using SO for much, much longer. Thought it was time to give back.

Answer (score 26):

Non clickable:

```
$("#ElementName").css("pointer-events","none");
```

Clickable:

```
$("#ElementName").css("pointer-events","auto");
```

Comment: Great solution !!

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#patient').unbind("click");
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: It's a neat solution!

Comment: This works for me, but how to make it clickable again??

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your need (Only one element or many, dynamic element creation or not) you can use :

1) A variable to check if the first click on the other element has been done

```
var isActive  = false;

$('.case').click(function() {  
    isActive = true;
});

$('#patient').click(function(){
    if(isActive === false)
        return false;

    //Your behaviour
});
```

2) Define the click function in the click event of the first element

```
$('.case').on('click',function() { 
    //Make element clickable 
    $('#patient').on('click',function(){
        //Your behaviour
    });
});
```

Then you can use [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the click event

Answer (score 1):

```
for first instance..add deactive class to patient div tag...

$('#patient').click(function() { 
if($(this).hasClass('deactive'))
 return;
else
//do what you want to do.
});

on case click...

$('.case').click(function() {  
$('#patient').removeClass('deactive');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger

```
$('#patient').addClass('active').trigger('click');
```

REFERENCE : [**.trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)