# How to disable href link and enable the link?

Tags: html

i want to make a archive.When link is clicked it should be disabled and if clicked again it should be enabled.How to make such link.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how a link works (or is supposed to work).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462682/set-element-to-unclickable-and-then-to-clickable/17462715#17462715

Comment: Please, be kind show us your attempts, to see your code and understand easier the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FfTmL/3/

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me!" />
<br /><br />
<input type="button" id="target" value="ENABLE" />
```

CSS:

```
.disabled{
    background:#ccc;
    color: #AAA;
    border: 1px solid #DDD

}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        if( $("#target").hasClass("disabled") ){
            $("#target").removeClass("disabled");
        }else{
            $("#target").addClass("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply id "buttonid" to ypur button rest will work as you desired.

```
$('#buttonid').on('click', function() {
if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
    // write anything if you want to perform any action when it is active
}
return false;
});
```

/* CSS part */

```
#patient { pointer-events: none; }
#patient.active { pointer-events: auto; }
```

Thanks...

Comment: There's no much effort in this answer... you have copy/pasted @Kalley answer of the question he posted above, not even remove the other OP ID's...

Comment: @Arkana Calm calm... just wanting to make sure he got to the answer no offense. Credit also goes to you.